# How to sort emails to folders basing on old .pst file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I have an Outlook 2010 connected via MS Exchange to my company's server, to the main company e-mail address. I had all the 13 thousand e-mails sorted manually in many different folders. I wanted to do local backup of the e-mails so I chose the archive option from File menu, but it did not only save the backup pst file, but also remove all the e-mails from the server. To restore them I used the "Recover Deleted Items" option, but now I have all the e-mails (even sent ones) in the inbox folder.

I have the archive.pst file and I also have backup of the .ost file from `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook` directory. How can I quickly recover each e-mail's location? I need to do it in the fast way and I cannot ask admin to do that. I already tried to copy the .ost file to Outlook's direcotry, but I get the "using old file" error.

Any help appreciated

Comment: There isn't a quick solution to your problem, the .OST is only a cache of the server, which is no longer valid. If you had asked before you restored 13k you would have had really easy options.

Comment: @Ramhound - and what were the options at that time?

Unfortunatelly I wanted to resolve the problem quickly and I brought me to where I am :(

Comment: @Ramhound - and in this situation - is there ANY solution other than moving the e-mails manually?

Comment: Your emails were moved not deleted from the server to a local archive.  You could have, if you had asked, just copied them back to the server keeping the same organization.

Comment: @Ramhound And now there is no way to do that? So I have to actually move them back manually?

Comment: You could move the emails off the server to yet another local archive, then  provided the archive that was originally made is indeed sorted, copy the emails back to the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24426/discussion-between-burtek-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I quickly recover each e-mail's location?

I am going to assume that all of your emails made it to the local .PST archive.  If that is the case I have confirmed the following should work.  You will have to first move the emails that are on the server to a new local .PST archive.  The reason you want to do this is the second step will copy 13k emails from the first archive back to the server.

Once you have completed this second backup make sure both archives have all your emails for good measure.  Once you have verified the original organized local .PST archive has all your emails, locate the inbox folder contained within the archive, right click and select "Copy Folder".

You will then prompted for the folder you want this copy to go to.  Select the Inbox on the server.  The purpose of this feature with Outlook is to move the emails off the server, in most cases, there are mailbox limits.

Comment: Almost. Bin, inbox, Sent etc are back (I can see them on my Exchange-connected android), same as all other folders in the root of the account. But mails put in inbox's subfolders haven't synced properly - I cannot see any of these messeges on my phone, although in each subfolder's properties I can see the same number next to both "offline folder" and "server folder". Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: They do show up in Outlook correct and I gave the server the time Outlook needed to sync the emails plus 3 more hours. I'm gonna reset the Exchange account's settings on other devices and see if that helps

Comment: For some reason Outlook doesn't want to sync inbox subfolders on my computer, but at the moment I'm ok with that and since the answer is good for the problem specified in my question I'm gonna accept it. Thanks for you help.

Comment: This isn't to anyone in particular.  I noticed I recieved a downvote.  I am trying to understand the reason for the downvote.  Please be kind and leave a comment, on the reason, the downvote was issued.